# How to access ApplicationRecord inside initializer script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any way to access `ApplicationRecord` and its `models` inside an initialization script? Like:

```rb
# config/initializers/start.rb
include ApplicationRecord

User.all.each do |user|
  # do stuff with users
end
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Is there an error message or an unexpected result? What do you actually try to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Konstantin Strukov, that's how I ended up doing

```rb
# config/initializers/start.rb
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  User.all.each do |user|
    # do stuff with users
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee your initializer in `config/initializers` will be executed after all gems' initializers, so if your initializer relies on ActiveRecord fully initialized (or any other moving part of the application) you'd better put the code into `config.after_initialize` block. The documentation is [quite explicit](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files) with regards to that.